# Type of Memory in a MIPS Processor

Tags: assembly, memory, mips, ram

I have a question regarding the type of memory that a MIPS processor actually uses. I know that when a MIPS program is assembled, different parts of the program will be stored in different areas of memory, according to whether it's static data, dynamic data, data to be allocated on the stack, or instructions. I know that the MIPS memory is divided into kernel space, Dynamic memory, Static memory, text memory for instructions, and stack memory. My question is, is this all RAM memory from the hardware point of view? Sometimes the static memory section of the MIPS memory is called ROM memory, but it can't be ROM as data may be overwritten. So is all of the MIPS memory just RAM memory? Are the kernel sections for the OS ROM memory or RAM, from a hardware perspective?

I tried looking online but I coulnd't find a clear answer to the hardware specifics of the processor memory.

Comment: That division into "kernel" or "static" memory etc. is not something dictated by the CPU, it's part of the OS. From the CPU's point of view it's all just a flat address space. Not even the "stack" is special, it's just a value in a register (and some instructions to manipulate this value, basically).

Comment: All the desktop CPUs I know of back to the 8080 and 6502 have had one pool of RAM that gets divided up by the OS, there aren't separate RAM chips or sticks for stack vs. heap vs. data.

Comment: The programming model separates code, data, other sections in the program file, which are then loaded to separate addresses in the process by the operating system.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude As i remember, in some CPU architectures user/kernel memory split and caching modes are hardwired by MMU, not a convention only.

Comment: @dimich: But that's normally a split of *virtual* address-space, right?  One example is modern x86-64 with "linear address masking" (LAM,https://www.phoronix.com/news/Intel-LAM-Linux-Kernel-May-2022), where the HW still checks that the top bit matches the top of the low 48 or 57 bits, but ignoring the check on the intervening bits can be enabled for either or both user(0) or kernel(1), so this ISA feature does actually bake in a user vs. kernel split down the middle of virtual address space.  (But that's big, and the same physical pages can be mapped by either or both, e.g. mmap + pagecache)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Fun fact: MIPS is one of the least "stacky" ISAs.  It doesn't have any special instructions like `push` or `pop` that treat a register as a stack pointer, just `addiu` and `lw`/`sw`.  (So normally you move the stack pointer once and then just load/store, not inefficiently add 4 after every store.  This is normal for a RISC.)  But unlike many ISAs, even hardware exception  / interrupt handling doesn't "push" anything anywhere; nothing in MIPS implicitly uses any register as a stack pointer even asynchronously.

Comment: (So interrupt handlers have to save all of the old state because HW doesn't.  That's why MIPS ABIs reserve 2 of the 32 GPRs as being asynchronously clobbered (`k0` and `k1` registers), so shouldn't be used for anything except in interrupt handlers.  I guess exception-return address is saved elsewhere in special regs.  Actually MIPS needs two exception-return addresses: first and second, because of the branch-delay slot.  It might have page-faulted while trying to run the branch delay instruction after a taken branch.  Or TLB-missed, since classic MIPS has SW TLB handling.)

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on your system design. MIPS itself has only one demand — "At CPU reset, address 0x1FC00000 must contain a startup code".

Code and read-only data may reside either in ROM or in RAM. The MIPS CPU does not make a difference between code and constant data — they can be mixed together. If they reside in RAM - they can still be protected from modification with virtual memory.

Writable data must reside in RAM. If it starts in ROM — it must be copied into RAM on program startup. Stack and heap are always in RAM. They are empty on program startup.

All of those configurations are possible:

- All code and RO-data are in ROM, writable data is in RAM. This is common in microcontroller systems.
- Kernel code and RO-data are in ROM, kernel data is in RAM, user programs (both code and data) are in RAM. May appear on some small computers (routers, mobile phones).
- Only the bootloader is in ROM. Kernel and user programs are in RAM. Used on most personal computers.
- The processor has only RAM. This can only work in a multi-processor system, as it requires someone to write a starting program into RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Now you have to distinguish between MIPS the processor and mips the chip product.  I assume you mean mips the core/architecture.

And as with any other purchased IP or architecture (arm, riscv, etc), it is the chip people that decide, sometimes the architecture puts limits on them but the chip people decide, not people that create the IP for the core processor.

Sadly documentation still uses terms like "memory map" making people think the whole thing has memory, ram, behind it and then well how does memory mapped I/O work does the I/O read the memory, and on and on with the confusion...

From a hardware perspective there is some bus (and here again if you are using one of the literally countless every other computer engineer had to make one or two mips cores in college mips cores, or a real one you bought and even there, the bus details vary by implementation) with some address and as a chip person you simply decide within architecture limits and within reason (that includes making a product you can sell or use) how to divide that address space up and what to put behind it.

static memory vs dynamic I assume you mean sram and dram.   In general dram does not just magically work when powered up.  You need some init or a lot of init and a typical/sane design you leave that to the software/bootloader folks, you wire up the control registers for the dram controller and phy into the address space of the processor and help them do it but software does that.  So.....if they have no dram then where can they run this code?

SRAM you tend to have some amount of on chip sram or possible off chip, but at least a small amount (kbytes) that the bootloader can use for very early boot tasks including getting dram or some other larger memory initialized.  sram is a generic term that spans a large range of solutions and implementations, but in general and for this answer it is logic that just comes up.  the hardware folks choose some part of the address space to locate this sram.

Same goes for flash/rom/etc non-volatile storage to hold the boot and other stuff, or some solutions do not have flash necessarily and the design is such that you download the firmware, your mouse and keyboard and such likely work this way that the logic on its own does enough of the usb bus to get the kernel driver to download the firmware for the peripheral into sram on the peripheral and then the peripheral resets and re-enumerates on the bus as a keyboard or mouse or camera or whatever.

You see this on a number of designs like arm based ones (phones, tablets, etc) where there may or may not be space in the processors address space for flash but instead the logic on its own can read an sd card and copy the contents into ram and the processor can see its own sram and can init and see dram, but not see the flash directly (in the address space as a readable memory).  One would expect some mips designs to do this too, but...its up to the chip people.

okay you said static data and dynamic data but you are asking about hardware.

kernel instructions and read/write memory and stack and heap, application instructions, read/write memory, stack, and heap are all JUST RAM.  Be it SRAM or DRAM.  It is just ram.

How how the MIPS architecture does cached vs not cached vs how the ARM architecture does it is different as far as I remember and then you have MMUs which in addition to providing protection (often) they also help you with memory management (all two thirds of the name if not three thirds).  An application can allocate 16 meg of "memory", expected to be linear from the
base address returned but that can be one/dozens/hundreds of individual, non-linear chunks of physical memory mapped into one linear virtual space using the mmu.

Your question leads to addressing as well physical memory since kernel vs application, kernel implies an operating system which implies, not requires, but implies the applications are in a virtual address space.  The kernel stack, heap, read/write, instructions, read only data is in one address space, likely physical.  The applications, plural, each have their own stack, heap, read/write, read only and instruction space.  For a number of reasons both will resemble some linear space where the programmer (indirectly by choosing a toolchain and libraries and such that know your target and have maybe divided it up for you but you are actually in control) chooses how to
divide up that memory into these various parts.  There are exceptions to the
rule when you get into embedded but for your generic linux/windows/mac machine consider it all dram and no magic memory for each thing.

In some embedded systems, in addition to having layers of caching, you may know about and choose for example to put certain things in an on chip sram space, like the stack or some performance critical code, using linker magic or mmu magic or other, so that you get the performance gain by using SRAM over cache or dram.  Consider this an exception not the rule.

For your typical operating system based general computing or server products like laptop/desktop/server, even smartphones and tablets, from a hardware perspective it is one huge linear physical address space implemented in dram.  The operating system folks divide that memory up by first taking space for themselves and then having some percentage be for applications.  The operating system folks define what the virtual space for each application looks like and assume that also looks like a flat linear space, backed by dram but through an mmu and caching.  (kernel will get cache benefits too no doubt).

> So is all of the MIPS memory just RAM memory?

Yep

> I tried looking online but I coulnd't find a clear answer to the hardware specifics of the processor memory.

You have to look at not only specific CHIPS (not MIPS cores, but mips BASED chips) and further than that you have to look at SYSTEMS based on those chips so while the chip folks have a wide range of options, (whatever they can think up that fits in the architecture) the folks that buy the chips and make the boards tend to have a small to wide range of options.   So for mips with how long it has been around assume an uncountable number of combinations and there is no way to search for that much less one answer that everyone uses.  There is not, you have to look at specific boards with specific chips and most of that is proprietary information but there are raspberry pi like products that are open-hardware-ish...with schematics and such and that use chips that you can get documentation without an NDA.  Of the dozens/hundreds/thousands of those you can then look at one at a time and see how they did it including the REFERENCE designs or board support packages for those individual board level products or reference designs for those products.

While technically one size does not fit all, it is a safe assumption, for solutions at a big enough level (running windows or linux or macos on a big computer like a desktop or server) that all the memory you are asking about is a dram backed linear space divided up by the operating system folks including rules about the virtual address space for applications.